# What guarantees does System.Numerics.Vectors provide about size and bit order?

Tags: c#, floating-point, endianness, simd, unsafe

I have implemented a vector-based c# approximation of Log. It includes unsafe code. It's been working fine in a number of environments, but on a recent deployment has fallen over. The implementation uses SIMD through the System.Numerics.Vectors library.

Unfortunately I cannot test on the system where the software isn't working. However, I would like to know which assumptions I made about the library are invalid:

- Does Vector<float>.Count always return a power of 2 ?
- Does Vector<UInt64>.Count == Vector.Count * 2 ?
- Can I take a pointer of a vector using Unsafe.AsPointer, then perform standard operations as though it were N packed numbers in memory ?
- Are there any processors that dotNet 4 runs on that have different endian-ness or don't store floats in IEEE754 format?

The code is as follows:

```
const float invLn2 = 1.44269504089f; // 1 / ln(2)
        const float pow2_126 = 8.5070592e+37f; //2^126

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Vector<float> QuickLog2(Vector<float> vecOrig)
        {
            //32 bit Float specification:
            //Leftmost bit is sign bit.
            //Next 8 bits are exponent
            //Next 23 bits are mantissa
            unsafe
            {
                var ints = Vector.AsVectorUInt32(vecOrig);

                var exponents = Vector.BitwiseAnd(ints, new Vector<uint>(0x7F800000));
                BitshiftVector23(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref exponents));

                var unsignedExponents = exponents - new Vector<uint>(127);
                var signedExponents = Vector.AsVectorInt32(unsignedExponents);
                var localMantissBitmask = Vector.AsVectorSingle(new Vector<UInt32>(0x807FFFFF));
                var maskedMantissas = Vector.BitwiseAnd(vecOrig, localMantissBitmask);
                var mantissas = maskedMantissas * new Vector<float>(pow2_126);

                var mantissasLogged = LogPolynomialFunction2(mantissas) * new Vector<float>(invLn2);

                Vector<float> floatExponents;
#if false
                floatExponents = Vector.ConvertToSingle(signedExponents);               
#else
                ConvertIntToFloatInPace(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref signedExponents));
                floatExponents = Vector.AsVectorSingle(signedExponents);
#endif

                return mantissasLogged + floatExponents;
            }
        }

        const float log10_2 = 0.30102999566398119521373889472449f;
        /// <summary>
        /// A vectorized implementation of Log10(N). Uses bitshift, bitmasks, and unsafe code.
        /// Does not have the same safety as Math.Log10: Behaviour for infities, zero, negative numbers are undefined.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vec">The vector to take the log of</param>
        /// <returns>The log, to the base 10, of the vector</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Accurate to about 10^-7, which is the limit of a 32 bit float anyway.
        /// In my (BS) tests, takes about twice as long to run on as Math.Log10(...), but operates on 8 numbers,
        /// so 4x faster.
        /// Reverts to Math.Log10(...) if vectors are not hardware accelerated. 
        /// Given the extra memory copies required, that will be much slower than using scalar code.
        /// It'll be nice once intrinsics make it into dotNet and we can replace this with a single instruction...
        /// </remarks>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Vector<float> QuickLog10(Vector<float> vec)
        {
            if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
                return QuickLog2(vec) * new Vector<float>(log10_2);
            else
            {
                float[] tmp = new float[Vector<float>.Count];
                vec.CopyTo(tmp);
                for (int i = 0; i < Vector<float>.Count; i++)
                    tmp[i] = (float)Math.Log10(tmp[i]);
                return new Vector<float>(tmp);
            }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static unsafe void BitshiftVector23(void* vector)
        {
            UInt64* asUlong = (UInt64*)vector;
            if (Vector<UInt64>.Count == 4)
            {
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
            }
            else if (Vector<UInt64>.Count == 8)
            {
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
                asUlong++;
                *asUlong = *asUlong >> 23;
            }
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < Vector<UInt64>.Count; i++)
                    asUlong[i] = asUlong[i] >> 23;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static unsafe void ConvertIntToFloatInPace(void* vector)
        {
            int* asInt = (int*)vector;
            if (Vector<int>.Count == 8)
            {
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
                *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                asInt++;
            }
            else if (Vector<UInt64>.Count == 16)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                }
            }
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < Vector<UInt64>.Count; i++)
                {
                    *(float*)asInt = *asInt;
                    asInt++;
                }
        }


        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static Vector<float> LogPolynomialFunction2(Vector<float> mantissas)
        {
            var zm1 = mantissas;
            var zp1 = mantissas + new Vector<float>(2f);
            var zm1Divzp1 = Vector.Divide(zm1, zp1);
            var squared = zm1Divzp1 * zm1Divzp1;
            var cur = zm1Divzp1;

            //Manual loop unwinding:
#if false
                var mantissasLogged = Vector<float>.Zero;
                for (float i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    var fac = 2f / (2f * i + 1f);
                    mantissasLogged += cur * new Vector<float>(fac);
                    cur *= squared;
                }
#else
            //i = 0;
            const float fac0 = 2f / (2 * 0 + 1);
            var mantissasLogged = cur * new Vector<float>(fac0);
            cur *= squared;

            //i = 1;
            const float fac1 = 2f / (2 * 1 + 1);
            mantissasLogged += cur * new Vector<float>(fac1);
            cur *= squared;

            //i = 2;
            const float fac2 = 2f / (2 * 2 + 1);
            mantissasLogged += cur * new Vector<float>(fac2);
            cur *= squared;

            //i = 3;
            const float fac3 = 2f / (2 * 3 + 1);
            mantissasLogged += cur * new Vector<float>(fac3);
            cur *= squared;

            //i = 4;
            const float fac4 = 2f / (2 * 4 + 1);
            mantissasLogged += cur * new Vector<float>(fac4);
#endif
            return mantissasLogged;
        }
```

EDIT: I put some simple tests into the program on startup. Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated == true; Vector.Count == 4; This vectorised Log gives the correct answer for the first two inputs, but incorrect for the second two. Perhaps the assumption that Unsafe.AsPointer(Vector) gives me a pointer to the vector elements as four consecutive floats is incorrect.

Log outputs:

```
DEBUG Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated: True 
DEBUG Vector<float>.Count: 4 
DEBUG Vector<Uint64>.Count: 2 
DEBUG MathUtils test input data: 5.967E+009,1.072E+006,9.521E+017,4.726E+000 
DEBUG MathUtils required output: 9.776,6.030,17.979,0.674 
DEBUG MathUtils actual output: 9.776,6.030,0.218,0.072
```

(Yet to have a chance to check the bit patterns...)

Comment: If the target supports AVX-512 then it cannot also be a weird architecture

Comment: @harold: how would you go about detecting AVX512 specifically, vs. AArch64 SVE, or something like a Cray-style [vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-1#Vector_machines)?  Endianness could still be a concern in theory for future architectures / future C# implementations, even if C# `float` is always IEEE binary32.

Comment: @PeterCordes the code gives the wrong result *now*, hypothetical futures did not cause that problem

Comment: @harold: oh I see, you were talking about the specific problem that caused the OP to ask this general question.  Not the title question in general.

Answer (score 0):

*IEEE 754* floating-point standard does not specify endianness, it definitely could be a problem here (depending on what you are running on)

You can use [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=netframework-4.8) and vary accordingly

> Indicates the byte order ("endianness") in which data is stored in
>   this computer architecture.

Comment: At least in theory, float endianness doesn't have to match integer endianness.  Is C# designed around the assumption that they are the same?  I think that's true on all modern CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Although x86 processors of today use little-endian storage for all types of data (integer, floating point, ect), there are a number of hardware architectures where floating-point numbers are represented in big-endian form while integers are represented in little-endian form, Also i belive some ARM processors are half endian even

Comment: So does `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` tell you the integer endianness or the float endianness?  Presumably it's the integer endianness.  You could check float-vs-int endianness by type-punning `1.0` to 32-bit integer and checking where the non-zero exponent bits are.  e.g. `== 0x0??0000` I didn't look up the bit-pattern.

Comment: @PeterCordes you raise a extremely good point, i cant see anything in the ECMA specs for C# (obviously it would be in the .net specs), but i am wondering if like you say, we just expect .net to be the same. however you could also do a negative or positive check as well, i.e the sign' (maybe)

Comment: Can you name an ISA that does use opposite endianness for int vs. float?  I forget what I found last time I looked for something about float-endianness, but I *think* all the major mainstrea / modern ISAs all have a float endianness that matches their integer endianness.  (And ISAs that can run in either mode like MIPS or ARM I think switch their float endianness with the same control as integer).  That would be consistent with a decision to provide only one endianness query in C# / .NET - no sense overcomplicating things if only obsolete systems are weird like that.

Comment: @PeterCordes i found this on wiki.. It says "*some arm processors*" and doesnt specify, im guessing they are very uncommon. Also goes on to say *"However, on modern standard computers (i.e., implementing IEEE 754), one may in practice safely assume that the endianness is the same for floating-point numbers as for integers, making the conversion straightforward regardless of data type."*

Comment: Alright, so it's definitely running on an Intel processor. I realised the endianess doesn't matter provided float and int64 have the same endianess. I've found out some more information and I think it's another issue - I'll update the question.